# ¿Cómo habilitar la API del Google Cloud Resource Manager?

Tags: google-developers-console, google-cloud-platform

Estoy desarrollando un aplicación en la que necesito crear, editar, actualizar e eliminar proyectos de mi consola de desarrolador de google.

El caso es que para ello según he leído en la documentación necesito habilitar el recurso organizaciones.

Me he puesto en contacto con el equipo de ventas de Google Cloud Platform solicitándolo pero no he obtenido respuesta alguna ya que por lo que he leído es necesario una invitación.

¿Alguien ha tenido el mismo problema que yo?

Necesito que aparezca el menú desplegable como el de la imagen de abajo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la documentación https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crea una organización primero.

aquí tienes la documentación para hacerlo.

https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/16966)

Comment: la respuesta es "crea una organización" y el enlace es un instructivo sobre como crear una organización.